# Is the physical dejarik a game of chance?

Tags: star-wars, rogue-one

Lakan Industries' holographic dejarik (aka holochess) is known as a challenging board game that combines skills and strategy like our traditional game of chess. But in *Rogue One* we can see in Jedha, at Saw Gerrera's hideout, some of his partisans gambling with an analog dejarik—in a hand-carved physical version—where one of them tosses and throws dice—probably to determine which type of piece, or a number of spaces, to move. By the way, the only word that one of the partisans says during the game is "Houjix!" which is the name of the bluish four legged creature. I haven't seen still images detailing the dice, but, as we know, dice games or card games, like sabacc, are categorized as games of chance, thus, is the physical dejarik a game of chance?

[image: Still image from Rogue One: A Star Wars Story]

[image: Analog Dejarik from Star Wars: Rogue One: The Ultimate Visual Guide]

Comment: why would the physical game be fundamentally different from the virtual version? Like many digital editions of games, the dice roll could also be virtual as part of the console table - This article says it's a tactical game, which a dice mechanic doesn't preclude - https://www.starwars.com/news/let-the-wookiee-win-dejarik

Comment: NKCampbell - Are you saying that in dejarik, players roll dice (virtually or physically) to move pieces around? If so (source?), probably the question most be rephrase as "is the dejarik...?"

Comment: Is monopoly a game of chance? Is Settlers of Catan a game of chance? These games involve dice rolls but also strategy. Just because a game has dice doesn't make it solely chance-based. A game that includes chance should challenge the players to make their own luck, to use chance to their advantage.

Comment: Palliser - I haven't found in C/L/EU a reference about the use of dice in dejarik but only in Rogue One. Are they really playing dejarik following all the standard rules or probably customizing some of them a little bit to make the game more 'easy' and profitable?

Comment: I haven't seen rouge one for a while but I think it is a game of chance

Comment: yeah @Palliser - I don't think we know if dice are involved in the game from a canon level - but if they are, I would argue, that just like any digital edition of most games, the dice are a virtual component in one way or another. So yes, if the question were rephrased to cover the game itself and not differentiate between a physical / virtual edition I think it would be better

Comment: I think you've answered your own question w/ that edit - looks like the physical edition isn't the 'real' version of the game - these terrorists are playing a home brew edition

Comment: NKCampbell - I think the existence of the physical dejarik is not confined to the one mentioned in the question (which could have been obtained in a looting). I remember the scene in 'Solo: A Star Wars Story' where Chewy tried to wipe the pieces off the table as if he has played the physical dejarik before.

Comment: @Palliser - you are remembering incorrectly - it was a hologram - Chewie breaks the table, which retcons the game's appearance in A New Hope - https://www.starwars.com/news/tippett-studio-solo-easter-egg

Comment: Yes@NKCampbell - but being Chewy a fan of dejarik, it looks like he thought that he wasn't playing the holochess but the analog. youtube.com/watch?v=UwmI1erCGug

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## It's a game of strategy

Even if we consider that dice or some element of randomness plays into the game (like many real-world games which would easily be considered strategy, such as RISK), we can presume, merely from it's introductory scene, that ultimately, it's a game of tactics. Let's look at the script:

```
                            THREEPIO
                     Now be careful, Artoo.
```

Be careful? About what? If this were a pure game of chance, there is nothing R2 can do to affect his position one way or the other - there is nothing to 'be careful' about if every aspect of the game is random.

R2 then makes his move. Chewie is not pleased:

```
                             THREEPIO
                     He made a fair move. Screaming about 
                     it won't help you.
```

If it were purely random, then the second half of Threepio's statement would still be valid, but - the first sentence is the important bit. "He made a fair move" - indicates a array of choices could have been made, some legal, some not, and R2 chose one that was both legal and advantageous. That means it was **strategic**.

Finally, the most famous line from the scene - Threepio suggests a new tactic: "Let the Wookiee win" - hard to do in a game of random chance.

One may also consider the board, being laid out with a grid-like pattern similar to chess - indeed, even called 'the chess scene' by Lucas according to [StarWars.com](https://www.starwars.com/news/let-the-wookiee-win-dejarik)

Finally - StarWars.com (surely a canon source) [states](https://www.starwars.com/news/let-the-wookiee-win-dejarik):

> The exact rules of dejarik have never been officially published, but
> the **tactical** game consisted of eight mythological and or existing
> creatures that had to confront each other on a holographic game table.
> **Each holomonster had its own strengths** that it would try to use when
> confronting the other creatures on the board. One of the known
> **tactical moves** was called the Kintan Strider death gambit.

As to the physical game - according to the source listed in the question - the 'physical' game appears to be a home made edition in lieu of the real game

[image]

Comment: Thanks @NKCampbell. I believe your answer covers the two versions of this game.